# lastcomm command shows no results

Tags: debian, logging, accounts

I'm trying to monitor a user's activities on my Debian server.
I found, after Googling that the `acct` package should help me log all commands and let me filter them by user.

I installed the package, some features seem to work (like the `ac` command). But the most important one for me: `lastcomm` shows no results:

```
root@myserver:~# ac
    total        7.75
root@myserver:~# sa
root@myserver:~# lastcomm
root@myserver:~#
```

I believe it logs all activities in `/var/log/account/pacct` am I right?

```
root@myserver:~# ls -l /var/log/account/     
total 0
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 0 Aug 23 14:33 pacct
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 0 Aug 23 14:23 pacct.0
```

I also found sources saying it logs in `/var/account/pacct` but that file/directory doesn't exist.

I'm out of ideas here, so anyone?

Comment: What happens if you run `accton` directly? I'm having a similar problem with Debian Lenny, but when I run `/usr/sbin/accton /var/log/account/pacct`, I get `Operation not permitted` as root. Still trying to get to the bottom of it, but `/etc/init.d/acct` masks this error message. So run manually, and see if accton kicks something similar out.

Comment: Is this solved yet?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the above output, `pacct` size is 0 byte. Start the `psacct/acct` service, doing something and try again.

Comment: I started the service like `service acct start` and ran some commands as a user. It stays empty

Comment: Make sure that your running kernel supports process accounting: `grep -i process_acct /path/to/kernel/.config`.

Comment: Hm, I'm having trouble finding my kernel. `/usr/src/` seems empty. This is some rented VPS by the way

Comment: Determine which VPS you are running with [virt-what](http://people.redhat.com/~rjones/virt-what/)

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the cron scripts have been added in `/etc/cron.daily` and `/etc/cron.monthly`.
Then launch the daily script to begin the accounting.

Comment: Cron scripts are active. I ran them, sadly no result